# Wordpress does not create multiple widget instances

Tags: php, wordpress

I thought Wordpress supports creating multiple widget instances in the same location but it looks like it does not in my code. I have created a plugin that shows recent posts. And in it I have created a widget that I want to be able to display multiple times in the same location.

```
class My_Recent_Posts_Widget extends WP_Widget {

    function __construct() {
        parent::__construct(
            'recent_posts', // Base ID
            esc_html__( 'Recent posts', 'text_domain' ), // Name
            array( 'description' => esc_html__( 'Display posts via widgets', 'text_domain' ), ) // Args
        );
    }
```

And I register the widget like this;

```
function register_my_recent_posts_widget() {
    register_widget( 'My_Recent_Posts_Widget' );
}
add_action( 'widgets_init', 'register_my_recent_posts_widget' );
```

The problem is if I try to place 2 instances of the same widget in the same location on the Widgets page in the admin the second widget does not show up.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
class My_Recent_Posts_Widget extends WP_Widget {
    public function __construct() {
        $widget_ops = array('classname' => 'my_widget_recent_entries', 'description' => esc_html__( "Your most recent Posts.",'text_domain') );
        parent::__construct('my-recent-posts', esc_html__('My Recent Posts Widget','text_domain'), $widget_ops);
        $this->alt_option_name = 'my_widget_recent_entries';
    }
```